# Bootstrap for Next.js app install bootstrap or react-bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, next.js, react-bootstrap

It is the first time I use Next.js. I would like to install bootstrap and I wonder what would be best for use Bootstrap in the application. If npm i bootstrap, or npm i react-bootstrap. Thanks.

Comment: You need to do both. React-Bootstrap has just the components, the styles are provided by Bootstrap.

Comment: oh great! thanks @brc-dd

Comment: Hi @brc-dd I am doing another project now but i am using Typescript, I wonder if you now how to install bootstrap for a Next.js Typescript project?

Comment: The setup is similar to a JS project, you just need to add one more (dev)dependency: [`@types/react-bootstrap`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-bootstrap), the rest will be handled by the typescript compiler.